# When Hikari was sick in the past, who slapped Taichi?

Tags: digimon

In My Sister’s Keeper, it was revealed that once in the past, Hikari collapsed from her puemonia while playing with Taichi, and she had to be hospitalised and nearly died. A grown woman yelled at Taichi blaming him for Hikari’s near-death, and slapped him across his face. Why wasn’t their mother doing anything to stop that woman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why wasn’t their mother doing anything to stop that woman?

Because that *was* their mother. As per [TV Tropes' article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/DigimonAdventureSupportingCast)' on Taichi and Hikari's parents:

> In a flashback, when Kari gets sent to the emergency room because of Tai's disobedience, Yuko slaps him in the face out of anger and yells at him. It's not a case of Abusive Parent and she didn't mean anything beyond scolding him, and almost anyone with a mom and [who has] made a big mistake in the past can attest to this being Truth in Television.